# Required parameters - Either/Or

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I created an "intent" that I want to collect some contact information from. I want either their phone number or email address. As most users don't want to give both, I want to make it required that they share one of the other.

Is there a way to do this from the web app? Is there a way to accomplish this thru fulfillment code? or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The either/or (or better put the if/else) logic can be achieved via follow up intents like this:

- Create an intent and ask your user if they rather give you their phone or their email
- Create a follow up intent for when the user replies with 'email' and another follow up intent for when the user replies with 'phone'. At the 'Responses' in each intent, ask for the user's email or address accordingly and then follow up the conversation as you'd do with any other intents.

To create follow up intents, hover over an intent at the intents page and click at the 'Add follow up intent' option.

If there isn't a screen input, consider that it may be difficult for the user to input their emails so make sure you do appropriate checks that it is a valid email format and of course ask your users for confirmation (ex. the submitted email is xyz@app.com. Shall I proceed?)

Comment: Awwwww, I think that's it! I'll probably include a 3rd option for users that give both email and phone number! I'll post screenshots when I get something working. Thanks Eliza!!

Comment: Ok, I think I found my problem again. Linearly, I think this answer works but in action, people provide content differently and I don't want the bot to repeat itself. We need to collect State OR City. We need the Email OR Phone. We also need Profession OR Specialty. If someone provides the email and specialty up front, how do I get Dialogflow to just ask for the City or State? Thank you Eliza for your first answer tho - differently helped!

Comment: Maybe by giving an example conversation flow I can help more. Keep in mind that you can also have an entity that it's getting any value (@sys.any) and you can check the value from a function at the fulfillment, as well as other system entities like @sys.email and @sys.phone; you can add your intent training phrases and responses for both of them and depending on your user's reply, you can respond accordingly

Comment: So I guess it would go like this.I have an intent setup to if find someone is looking for a job with a required parameter of profession. I have followup intents setup to collect desired location and then the contact info. So the problem is, some people lead with the location in the job search, eg "I'm looking for a job in NYC." It would then ask for profession. Then, it would ask for location again. I have a model built where it detects the info given up front and has a path from there, but with a "require either/or" feature, I think it would be more scalable.

Comment: I have a [request](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dialogflow/ax74zabRwbA;context-place=topicsearchin/dialogflow/author$3Ame$20is$3Afirstpost) in now

Answer (score 2):

In a given intent, you can enable "use webhook for slot-filling" to have Dialogflow call your webhook each time the intent is matched.

https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#slot_filling

In your fulfillment code, you can check the presence of either parameter and respond appropriately if neither is provided.